# Memcached reflecting changes automatically from the built in User model, how?

Tags: python, django

I am using memcached in my code to represent some lists in web. I am doing something like this,

```
from django.core.cache import cache

#inside view
cache_key='somekey'
cache_time=sometime
data=cache.get(cache_key)

if not data:
    #some code
    cache.set(cache_key,data,cache_time)

return render(...)
```

It is working perfectly. Cache is serving the pages. But here I am observing that, any changes in the database in the build in User model is getting reflected in the cache automatically. how is this happening?
And my 2nd question is, what is the best way to reflect the database changes in the memcached. I already tried to maintain, flags in the database using a trigger. It is working, but it is not possible to maintain different flags for every cache in the db as some urls has `<int:pk>` in them. Any help will be appreciated.